# SPSS Incorrectly Displaying CHAR

Tags: sql, db2, spss, spss-modeler

I have a DB2 database connected to SPSS Modeler v.17. Currently most of the tables in DB2 use a unique identifier column that is the CHAR(16) FOR BIT DATA type. This column displays fine in DB2, but when I query the data from within SPSS the values are just displayed as small squares and other unrecognizable shapes. I am thinking that SPSS cannot read the CHAR(16) FOR BIT DATA in its current setup, so my question is how do you get SPSS to display CHAR(16) FOR BIT DATA correctly?

Comment: And what do you need to use the bit data for in SPSS?

Comment: The bit data is used as the primary/foreign key for most of the tables in the database that we are pulling data into SPSS from.

Comment: SPSS doesn't support binary data types, but that doesn't necessarily mean you can't use the data. It's still the same data, except that it's being displayed using a character set that doesn't have a printable character for that value. Try using it in a join, it should still work.

Comment: Is this not essentially the same question as http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/126780/db2-database-conversion-workbench-issue?noredirect=1#comment234445_126780 ?